# select2, I want to remove the image after finishing selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

in the first image everything went according to plan, but when finished selecting (picture 2), the image looks too big, I wish I could get rid of the image after finishing selecting.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa8hD.png) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PEAK.png)

Javascript

```
   function formatData(data) {
    if (!data.id) {
        return data.text;
    }
    let imgProfile = $(data.element).data("src");
    var $result = $(
        `<span class='d-flex d-flex justify-content-between'>${data.text} <img src="/img/${imgProfile}" style="max-height:60px;"> </span>`
    );
    return $result;
}

$("#taskPIC").select2({
    placeholder: "Person in charge(PIC)",
    allowClear: true,
    templateResult: formatData,
    templateSelection: formatData
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="taskPIC" name="user_id[]" style="width: 100%">
                                <option></option>
                                @foreach ($user as $item)
                                <option value="{{ $item->id }}" data-src="{{ $item->img }}">
                                    {{ Str::limit($item->name, 20) }}
                                </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
```

CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when an item is selected?  By using `templateSelection`, you are saying you want to display that image there.  Have you tried removing `templateSelection`?

Comment: i solved this with code bellow

`    $("#taskPIC").on("select2:close", function(e) {
        var data = $(e.target)
            .next()
            .find("img");
        data.addClass("d-none");
    });`